# How to seperate a part of value that comes after a pranteses with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a mysql table that has values such as

> 604)سیدرضی40
>   or
>   38)صبای 42

I want to extract this column into two columns and separate before `)` and after `)`  in this new columns.
I am wondering how to use php code to separate these values. For example I want to convert above example to

> column 1:
>    604   38
>     column2:
>   صبای 42  سیدرضی40

I can use strrchr function as bellow:

```
<?php echo strrchr("604)سیدرضی40",41);?>
```

and converting 604)سیدرضی40 to  )سیدرضی40  but it is not exactly what I want. 
I want to have "604" and "سیدرضی40 " as result.

As an English example I want convert "767)abc" into two part: "767" and "abc".

Comment: Just use `explode('(', $string)`

Comment: @BizzyBob: explode('(', "604)سیدرضی40"); returns nothing for me!

Comment: sorry used the wrong parenthesis.  should have been a ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function will break a string into parts by the specified character(s).  It also excludes that character from the results, so the `)` will be excluded, just as you want.

```
$string = '604)سیدرضی40';

$split = explode(')', $string);

var_dump($split);

//array(2) { 
//    [0]=> string(3) "604" 
//    [1]=> string(14) "سیدرضی40"
//}
```

Comment: as @bizzybob said  <?php print_r (explode(")","604)سیدرضی40"));?> worked for me.